# Function searchissue() from egit don't return all issues in a GitHub repository

Tags: github, egit, github-api

I am trying to find issues from a repository in the GitHub, but when I use the searchissues()  function from the  IssueService class, that only returns 10 issues. The repository that i am search has more then 40 issues registred.

How can i return all de issues registred in my repository?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
    client.setCredentials("xxxxxx", "xxxxx");

    int openIssue = 0;
    int closedIssue = 0;


    RepositoryService repositoryService = new RepositoryService(client);
    IRepositoryIdProvider repoId = new repositoryId("purifycss","purifycss");

    IssueService issueService = new IssueService(client);

    for(SearchIssue search : issueService.searchIssues(repoId, "all", " ")){
        System.out.println(search.getTitle() + " " + search.getState() + " " + search.getNumber());

        if(search.getState().equalsIgnoreCase("open"))
            openIssue++;

        if(search.getState().equalsIgnoreCase("closed"))
            closedIssue++;

    }

    System.out.println(openIssue + " " + closedIssue);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be related to [pagination in GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/).

Check out the test [`org.eclipse.egit.github.core.tests/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/tests/live/IssueTest.java` #L138-L156](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/6e30f1041361334024f05ae62d74ec222565ab13/org.eclipse.egit.github.core.tests/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/tests/live/IssueTest.java#L138-L156): it shows how to iterate over *pages* of results, instead of the results directly (limited by default)

```java
    IssueService service = new IssueService(client);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(IssueService.FILTER_STATE, IssueService.STATE_CLOSED);
    PageIterator<Issue> iterator = service.pageIssues("schacon", "showoff",
            params, 1);
    assertNotNull(iterator);
    assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
    Collection<Issue> page = iterator.next();
    int pages = iterator.getLastPage();
```