# List all issues in repository

Tags: java, github, github-api

I want to list all issues into all repository under all organizations. 
I tried this code:

```
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient(host);
        client.setCredentials(user_name, password);

        RepositoryService repository = new RepositoryService(client);
        IssueService issues = new IssueService(client);

        OrganizationService organization = new OrganizationService(client);

        List<Repository> orgRepositories = repository.getOrgRepositories("eMerchantPay");

        for (int i = 0; i < orgRepositories.size(); i++) {
            Repository get = orgRepositories.get(i);
            String name = get.getName();
            System.out.println("Repository name " + name);

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            List<Issue> issues1 = issues.getIssues(user_name, name, map);

            for (int x = 0; x < issues1.size(); x++) {
                Issue get1 = issues1.get(x);
                String title = get1.getTitle();
                System.out.println("Issue name " + title);
            }

        }
```

How I can do this with org.eclipse.egit.github.core library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`org.eclipse.egit.github.core.service.IssueService`](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/IssueService.java) for fetching all issues of a given repo.

See an [example in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31016767/6309), where you will get the *pages* of issues:

```
IssueService service = new IssueService(client);
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put(IssueService.FILTER_STATE, IssueService.STATE_CLOSED);
PageIterator<Issue> iterator = service.pageIssues("schacon", "showoff",
        params, 1);
```